# Wordpress admin panel pop up window blank

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I think photos speak for themselfs.
basically all this windows that open inside wp admin are blank.
is there any known solution?
Thanks

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAhqJ.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHpRg.png)

Comment: this can be happening because some plugin or configuration. Disable all your plugins and configure your site URLs. Also, open the browser console and check for errors (post them on the question).

Comment: Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://example.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=wp-super-cache& does not permit framing.

Comment: Did you disabled plugins? What are your server configs (apache, nginx, configs)?

Comment: Thank you, @Robert - your solution worked for me. Maybe you should create and accept the answer for other people to know. And link in yout comment is invalid.

Comment: Thank you. In Addition to `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` I also had to change CSP to `Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'self'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install "Ignore X-Frame headers" plugin on chromium based browsers or "Ignore X-Frame-Options Header" on firefox.

**--This fixes the issue from the client side !**